# How to continuize a discrete time Markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, discrete-time

I want to use an advanced Monte Carlo techniques to a discrete time Markov chain (DTMC), thus I need to continuize my DTMC. What is the best way to do that? I want to measure some observable along path of this Markov chain, thus I want a continuization way that give me same sample mean.

Comment: I am not an expert on MC techniques and do not really understand your question, but I hope this might: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361588/two-different-ways-of-constructing-a-continuous-time-markov-chain-from-discrete?rq=1